# Can I make a different bot instance for each server my discord bot joins, so that variables set in different servers don't effect another?

Tags: bots, discord.py

My bot runs a simple server economy, and the problem I'm getting is that if the bot is in multiple servers, any users added in one server also count in the other servers. Is there any way to have separate bot instances for each server its in?

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There sure is!

Get a list of each server the bot is in using `bot.guilds`

For example:

```
botguilds = bot.guilds
```

Then

```
for guild in botguilds:
#create a new .json file, when creating it, just use guild.id
```

This way, for ever guild that the bot is in, it will create a .json file. Instead of opening a certain .json file, you can open `str(guild.id`

All this does, is create a .json file for every guild the bot is in, and opens the .json file for that specific guild. I think everything else can be done the same!

Comment: I'm sorry, but how would I go about creating a json file with the name of guild.id? I've been using dictionaries mostly so I'm still learning how to use json data