# Creating database files for each server that has my bot

Tags: python, database, discord, discord.py, bots

My bot runs a simple server economy, and the problem I'm getting is that if the bot is in multiple servers, any users added in one server also count in the other servers. Is there any way to have separate bot instances for each server its in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I make a different bot instance for each server my discord bot joins, so that variables set in different servers don't effect another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554558/can-i-make-a-different-bot-instance-for-each-server-my-discord-bot-joins-so-tha)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **json**, put the server id as the key to a dictionary that takes user id as a key :

```
{
"server1": {"userA":..., "userB":...}, 
"server2": {"userA":..., "userC":...},
...
}
```

If you are using **sql**, use a composed id (server+user).

Note that this is one way of coding out of many.

Answer (score 0):

You can just make a dictionary with the names and the id s of the server and then regarding to the database u use, you can just take the datas from database with just calling the name of the server from dictionary.
Example:

```
serverdic["server_name"]
```